# Date Picker differencing half day and full day

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, date

in my project I want to save the leave of a temp where he took half day or full day from the calender.

Comment: Use a normal datepicker + a radio button "half" or "full"?

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail please? Your question's rather vague.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose times by using the plugin at http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/. This supports increments so by setting a 12 hour increment you can basically force to think in half day mode.

I implemented a version of this a little while ago. You can see a version of this at http://www.thewebdes.co.uk/dev/leave/. There's a link on there where you can get all the code I wrote for the project. I've commented it throughout.

Hope it helps.

Scott